# Small inter nuclear separation limit for Diatomic molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

Let’s take the a simple $H_2^+$ molecule, where there is only electron which is $r_a$ away from the first proton and $r_b$ away from the other one.

Let’s call the separation between the two protons $R$.

As $R\rightarrow \infty$, the electron will stick to one of the two protons, so the wavefunction will be: $$ \phi =  N_{\pm}(1s_a \pm 1s_b).$$

I recognise the two solutions as the gerade and ungerade orbitals. The $1s$ means ground state around each proton.

I can work out the normalisation constant to be $$ N_{\pm} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(1\pm S)}}, \, S = \int 1s_a 1s_b \mathrm{d}^3 r $$

**Now** in the limit of $R \rightarrow 0$, the gerade solution becomes just $1s$ which makes sense, but the ungerade is not defined - what happens to it?

Comment: In what way is the existing (accepted!) answer unsatisfactory?

Comment: What?  Where does it say it’s unsatisfactory? I accepted it after the bounty had been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think physically about the shape of the odd state.  It has a nodal plane at the midpoint of the line connecting the two nuclei; this is the only node to the wave function.  As the nuclei become coincident, that nodal plane ends up passing through the combined nucleus; since this is the only node, the resulting wave function is the $2p_{z}$ state, if the axis of the molecule was originally oriented along the $z$-axis.

You will not get this by taking a limit of $1s$ wave functions.  When the nuclei are very far apart, the overlap integral that determines the energy difference between the odd and even states is very small, and the wave function in the vicinity of each nucleus looks very close to a $1s$.  However, as you the distance between the nuclei gets comparable to the Bohr radius $a_{0}$ or smaller, the true wave function will need to be constructed out more than just $1s$ basis states.  When the separation is small comparable to $a_{0}$, you get a very complicated wave function, although it simplifies to just the $2p$ state once the separation gets very small compared to $a_{0}$.

Comment: So you're saying that physically the ungerade solution becomes the 2p state, but that mathematically you can't get it unless I leave the 1s-centric description.
But what's special about the the 2p? Why does it not become the 3d?

Comment: @SuperCiocia It's the fact that the u state always has a planar node midway between the nuclei.  It evolves to become the nodal plane of the 2p orbital.  A d state could not be the limit, because it has additional nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Psi(\vec{r})$ be $1s_a$ wave function and $\Psi(\vec{R}+\vec{r})$ be $1s_b$ wave function. As $\vec{R} \to 0$ we have for ungerade state:
$$
\phi_{-}(\vec{r}) = N_{-}(\Psi(\vec{R}+\vec{r})-\Psi(\vec{r})) \approx N_{-} \nabla\Psi(\vec{r})\vec{R}
$$
Thus the limit (not normalized) is $\nabla\Psi(\vec{r})\vec{n}$, where $\vec{n} = \vec{R}/|\vec{R}|$. This function has nodal plane as Buzz said. Also it has discontinuity at $\vec{r} = 0$. But I think this function does not coincide with $2p$ state.

Comment: Why wouldn't it coincide with the 2p state? It needs to limit to an eigenstate and the 2p state is the only one with the correct symmetry. If you want to argue that it doesn't, a vague "don't think so" doesn't really cut it.

Comment: 2p state has continuous wave function and this one has discontinuity  at $\vec{r} = 0$

Comment: I know it doesn’t go exactly to the 2p, you can show mathematically that at low R it scales differently.

Comment: @SuperCiocia, the question was about limit of $N_{-}(1s_a - 1s_b)$. I give explicit formula for this limit. It is clear that $R\to 0$  limiting function constructed from hydrogen states is far from real wave  function.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, I was replying to Emilio since it seemed the wasn’t convinced.